# Table replication (materialized view) Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, replication, materialized-views

I'm trying to configurate table replication, which is located on remote database (db) using materialized view (mw) and database link (dblink). 
There is the point:

- I'm creating table on the 1st db (tb)
- creating dblinks from the 1st db to the second and backward
- creating mw on the 2nd db as select from tb and set refreshing time 2 min

But it doesn't refresh, and if I create mw on the 1st db as select from tb it refreshs

What should I do to configurate refreshing of mw?

---

**MASTER SITE:**

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK to_ora2_connected 
USING 'ora2';

drop table my_table
create table my_table
(
  field varchar(20) primary key,
  field2 number
);
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON my_table;
```

**SNAPSHOT SITE:**

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK to_ora1_connected 
USING 'ora1';

select * from my_table@to_ora1_connected;

drop materialized view my_table_mw;
create materialized view my_table_mw
  build immediate
  refresh complete start with sysdate
  next sysdate  + 0.00175 
  as select * from my_table@to_ora1_connected;
```

---

```
insert into my_table values ('note2', 2);
select * from my_table;
select * from my_table@to_ora1_connected;
select * from my_table_MW;
```

---

alert log:

```
Errors in file c:\app\ora1\diag\rdbms\ora2\ora2\trace\ora2_j000_3032.trc:
ORA-12012: ошибка при автоисполнении задания 63
ORA-04052: ошибка во время поиска удаленного объекта SYSTEM.SYS@TO_ORA1_CONNECTED
ORA-00604: ошибка на рекурсивном SQL-уровне 3
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
ORA-02063: предшествующий line из TO_ORA1_CONNECTED
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2558
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2771
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_IREFRESH", line 685
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_REFRESH", line 195
ORA-06512: на  line 1
```

and that failure happens every 10 sec:

```
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: задан недопустимый параметр
O/S-Error: (OS 1) Неверная функция. !
```

"задан недопустимый параметр" - an invalid parameter;
"Неверная функция" - incorrect function;
"ошибка при автоисполнении задания" - error when auto-execute the job
"ошибка во время поиска удаленного объекта" - Error while searching for the remote object;
     "ошибка на рекурсивном SQL-уровне 3" - Error on recursive SQL-level 3

Comment: You've committed the change?

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat, Yes

Comment: What is the `job_queue_processes` set to on the snapshot site?  Do you see an entry in `dba_jobs` to do the refresh?  Is that job ever set to run?  Does it show any failures?

Comment: @Justin Cave

job_queue_processes integer 1000;

select * from dba_jobs

I see this entry, 16 failures

Comment: @EugeneMikulich - OK.  The failures would have generated entries in the database alert log.  Pull up the alert log, find the stack trace, and post that here.

Comment: @Justin Cave. 
"ORA-12012: ошибка при автоисполнении задания 63
ORA-04052: ошибка во время поиска удаленного объекта SYSTEM.SYS@TO_ORA1_CONNECTED
ORA-00604: ошибка на рекурсивном SQL-уровне 3
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
ORA-02063: предшествующий line из TO_ORA1_CONNECTED
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2558
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2771
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_IREFRESH", line 685
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_REFRESH", line 195
ORA-06512: на  line 1"

Comment: and that failure happens every 10 sec - "OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: задан недопустимый параметр
O/S-Error: (OS 1) Неверная функция. !".
"задан недопустимый параметр" - an invalid parameter;
"Неверная функция" - incorrect function;
"ошибка при автоисполнении задания" - error when auto-execute the job
"ошибка во время поиска удаленного объекта" - Error while searching for the remote object;
"ошибка на рекурсивном SQL-уровне 3" - Error on recursive SQL-level 3

Comment: It would be easier if you edited your post to include this information rather than having us try to read data in comments.  It appears, though, that the database link was configured with an incorrect password.

Comment: @Justin Cave, this is strange, because all users have the same password.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using on both sides?  Any chance that one of the two systems is using case-sensitive passwords while the other doesn't?  Do other queries against the database link appear to work?

Comment: @Justin Cave both are 11.2g. I created these two databases on a single server

Comment: @EugeneMikulich - Well, the error is telling you that the password is incorrect.  How did you define the database link?  Are you using a fixed username and password?  Are you connecting as the current_user?  Either the password is incorrect or you aren't connecting to the database you think you are connecting to.

Comment: @Justin Cave, the code is written in my first sentence. And when I use dblink in select * from my_table@to_ora1_connected it works. I will try to re-create dblink in a different way.

Comment: The problem was in dblink. I created dblink (fixed user) and now it works. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in dblink. I created dblink (fixed user) and now it works. Thank you for helping!

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK to_ora1_connected
connect to user identified by password
USING 'ora1';
```